# query error on where clause at subquery

Tags: mysql

i have a error on my query

this my query

```
SELECT a.id_stock, a.color, a.size, (SUM(IFNULL(a.barang_masuk,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(a.reject,0)) - IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(IFNULL(qty,0)) AS SUMqty FROM transaksi WHERE transaksi.id_stock = a.id_stock GROUP BY id_stock
),0)) AS sold FROM stock a
WHERE a.no_barang='10' AND sold>0
GROUP BY a.no_barang, a.color, a.size
ORDER BY color, size ASC
```

and this the error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'sold' in 'where clause'
```

have any suggest to settle this??
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom aliases are not treated by where clause you need to use `HAVING` for this

```
SELECT a.id_stock, a.color, a.size, (SUM(IFNULL(a.barang_masuk,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(a.reject,0)) - IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(IFNULL(qty,0)) AS SUMqty FROM transaksi WHERE transaksi.id_stock = a.id_stock GROUP BY id_stock
),0)) AS sold FROM stock a
HAVING a.no_barang='10' AND sold>0
GROUP BY a.no_barang, a.color, a.size
ORDER BY color, size ASC
```

For the problem i guess you cannot use having before group by you can use subselect

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
    SELECT a.id_stock, a.color, a.size, (SUM(IFNULL(a.barang_masuk,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(a.reject,0)) - IFNULL((
        SELECT SUM(IFNULL(qty,0)) AS SUMqty FROM transaksi WHERE transaksi.id_stock = a.id_stock GROUP BY id_stock
    ),0)) AS sold FROM stock a

    HAVING a.no_barang='10' AND sold>0 
 /* you can use where and having both in same query like WHERE a.no_barang='10' HAVING sold>0 */

    ORDER BY color, size ASC ) q  GROUP BY q.no_barang, q.color, q.size
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT a.id_stock, a.color, a.size, (SUM(IFNULL(a.barang_masuk,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(a.reject,0)) - IFNULL((
    SELECT SUM(IFNULL(qty,0)) AS SUMqty FROM transaksi WHERE transaksi.id_stock = a.id_stock GROUP BY id_stock
),0)) AS sold FROM stock a
WHERE a.no_barang='10' 
GROUP BY a.no_barang, a.color, a.size
HAVING sold>0
ORDER BY color, size ASC
```

[**Unknown Column In Where Clause**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause)

[**How to use GROUP BY after the Having clause Mysql**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186677/how-to-use-group-by-after-the-having-clause-mysql)

Comment: i still found on error, i use the second query from your answer, the the error 1054 - Unknown colomn 'a.no_barang' in 'having clause'

Comment: @Hans Have you read my comments *WHERE a.no_barang='10' HAVING sold>0*

Comment: after i try with second query but the result is just 1 row, the query is group are row as one row with sum(sold)